# Comparing two models using "anova" but with type III SS?

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, ancova

Recent research have forced me to do a lot of reading on the different type of sum of squares (SS) when performing ANOVA in R. I have successfully done type 2 and type 3 SS ANOVA on single models using several different packages.

However, I now need to perform ANCOVA. I need to compare two different models using the "anova" function - one with interaction and one without. Is there a way to perform type III SS ANOVA to compare the two different models? Is there any need or sense to do such a thing? My reason for wanting to perform type III is because I have unequal sample size in the factors (categorical variable).